# jQuery Isotope add custom class and count filtered items

Tags: jquery, count, jquery-isotope

How can i add a custom class to this jQuery Isotope filtering and count the filtered items from isotope:

```
    $(function(){
var $container = $('#wrap-planspiel'),
      filters = {};

  $container.isotope({
        animationEngine : 'css',
        itemSelector : '.hexblock'
  });

  // filter buttons
  $('select').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    // store filter value in object
    // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
    var group = $this.attr('data-filter-group');

    filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
    // console.log( $this.find(':selected') )
    // convert object into array
    var isoFilters = [];
    for ( var prop in filters ) {
      isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
    }
    console.log(filters);
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
  });

      $('.filter a').click(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
      }

      var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
      // change selected class
      $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');
          var group = $this.parent().data('filter-group');
          filters[ group ] = $this.data('filter-value');
          var isoFilters = [];
            for ( var prop in filters ) {
              isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
            }
            console.log(filters);
            var selector = isoFilters.join('');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
            return false;
      });      

});
```

There is an example from desandro but the class remains after reseting all filters: http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/3nY9V/

Comment: And? Was the filtered items counting example I provided helpful?

Comment: Yes it was. Thank you. I need to add custom classes to each selected item too.

Comment: Well, since the hidden items you're counting have the class .isotope-hidden applied, can't you just use that property to target them? What I mean is - is it really necessary (for what you want to achieve in the end which I can't know of course) to add a custom class to items that are already "marked" by the .isotope-hidden class?

Comment: For the project i am working on it is needed that filtered items got a n additional custom class. Like in my example a custom class "is-filtered" is been added but after reset the filtering, class "is-filtered" still remains and thats my problem. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: After resetting the filtering (meaning no checkbox is selected), you can simply .remove() your custom class from all items, if you store them in a jQuery object with $items = $('.item'); as shown in the fiddle.

Comment: I got a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/45/ Counting is working perfectly but reseting the "is-filtered" Class isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Good that my answer helped to solve your initial question; maybe you could mark it as correct... But now, what do you mean by "resetting" .is-filtered? Could you explain a bit more what that is supposed to do or improve? Is, for example, a specific filter not giving the right number? Whatever combination I select in your fiddle, I get the right number alerted - as far as I can tell?!

Comment: The counting part is working like it should be. I meant reseting the is-filtered class when i deselect all options. Example: If i select something from the select/option list the filtered items are getting "is-filtered" class. When i deselect those then "is-filtered" should be removed.
I hope its clear now.

Comment: Hang in there, I think I know what you think.

Comment: This is the first Screen: http://d.pr/i/2Kb7 No options selected  
http://d.pr/i/U7yB Some options selected  
http://d.pr/i/bMI8 All options deselected but the class is-filtered remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, sorry to understand so slow, looking at it now in Chrome's devtools. So:

1. On load of your page (sandbox or fiddle) for the very first time, all 28 Isotope items are shown; an item has, for example, the "produkt-element flutlicht w-100w warmwhite isotope-item" classes, but no element has the "is-filtered" class, because no filtering has taken place yet
2. Then, one selects, for example, *Flutlicht* in the dropdown menu
3. Now, the item has also the "is-filtered" class added to the previous classes
4. Then, one selects *Alle Leuchtenarten* from the dropdown menu
5. Now, the page looks like in **1.** but the item still has the "is-filtered" class

Well, that comes not as a surprise, because now you are always **inside** the filter function, so all items are indeed filtered - but filtered for *Alle Leuchtenarten* and *Alle Lichtfarben* and *Alle Leistungen*, that's why all 28 items are shown **as if** your page has just loaded for the very first time :) But - why worry about that? You see what I mean?

Spotted another issue: when one does the above, you sometimes have gaps between items in your box when going back to show all 28 items. You need a call to reLayout somewhere or you have to rely on the viewer to resize the window to kick the layout filling mechanism.

Comment: There i found a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/47/ This does exactly what i needed. Maybe is helpfully for others.

Comment: Schön daß es jetzt klappt. Nur reLayout nicht vergessen, um "Löcher" zu vermeiden, wenn nichts, also alles, gefiltert ist ;)

Comment: Ich habe den isotope-script so bearbeitet das die animation garnicht stattfindet :-) Habe nur die filterung benötigt.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply count the filtered items like so http://jsfiddle.net/3nY9V/1/

Answer (score 2):

Just found that this exact example (counting the visible items) is given in [the isotope docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html).

```
$container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete',
  function( isoInstance, laidOutItems ) {
    console.log( 'Isotope layout completed on ' +
      laidOutItems.length + ' items' );
  }
);
```